# RelativeLayout - can't make views the same vertical size if they are horizontally aligned

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a layout which has two `CardView`'s and looks like this:

[image]

I wanted the right card to be fixed width (90dp) and the left one to automatically resize and fill the remaining space. I have currently done it like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/inventory_host_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/inventory_last_scanned_wrapper_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/inventory_scanned_infobox_wrapper_card">

            ...

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/inventory_scanned_infobox_wrapper_card"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            ...

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Left one can grow, so I also wanted the right card to always be the same height as the left one. Usually I do that kind of alignment by setting both `layout_alignTop` and `layout_alignBottom` properties to other `View` but those properties are not available this time, probably because that would create a circular reference (although I don't really understand how horizontal alignment could affect vertical). What to do? I have explored several other options but always get back to the same point except hardcoding heights or setting them programmatically which of course I want to avoid.

Comment: It looks like it'd be easier with LineraLayout. Did you try that?

Comment: Or ConstraintLayout :)

Comment: I tried both of them. `LinearLayout` lets me align both cards next to each other by setting weights, but I can't affect vertical size of either card. I don't have much experience with `ConstraintLayout` but when I did I arrived at the same problem as with RelativeLayout - it doesn't allow circular references so aligning one to other automatically disallows me to do it opposite way.

Comment: Another idea was setting right card height to `match_parent` and left one's to `wrap_content`. That would theoretically make parent height as big as the left card's and then align right one to it. But practically by setting that option parent expands to whole height of the screen.

Comment: I think that you should make a research about ConstraintLayouts :) It's worth it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where and why are you getting circular reference errors? Just set

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/inventory_last_scanned_wrapper_card"
```

on the card at the right side and everything should work.

Comment: IDE doesn't allow me to choose it from the list so I suspected it has to do something with circular reference. I also repeatedly tried to set it directly in XML and it was still glitching. But now after your advice I tried it one more time and... boom. It worked :) Thanks. I guess I missed something before.